# How find references for MVC controller methods in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Coming from a long period of WebForms development, I recently began working with MVC. One thing that struck me, is that since controller methods are not called directly from code, Visual Studio won't pick up any references to them.

[image: Silly example code image]

I understand the reason why there is no reference count, but it can be problematic sometimes. Let's say I rewrite a controller method to accomodate some new requirement, perhaps a certain call to the method needs additional data or a modified result. But perhaps that method, or endpoint if you will, is being called from several places, and the change I made breaks the result handling for those other calls. I would like to be able to easily find all the code in my solution, which is going to invoke the endpoint.

Currently I tend to copy the method name and perform a regular text search in the entire solution, which works rather well as long as the method name isn't too generic. If the method name is "Index", it can be a long day.

Are there any recommendations on how to simplify this, such as coding conventions, plugins or otherwise? **I.E. how can I locate from where the endpoint will be invoked?**

I currently use Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise, but solutions working in other versions as well are preferred - to make the answer useful for as many as possible.
Thanks in advance / Culme

UPDATE: I learned a lot based on the comments and replies I got. Apart from what is mentioned below, I also decided to try and keep my controller method names unique and identifiable, to simplify finding where they are being used. As an example, instead of just "Index", I'll try to use "Fidgets_IndexController" or something similar. That way, a simple text search will go a long way for locating calling code.

Comment: You can just right click -> find usages in Visual Studio?

Comment: *What* issue? Are you trying to solve a specific problem? The controller actions are the *endpoints* called by *browsers*. Just as you wouldn't normally find any references to a WebForm class , you wont' find references to controller actions

Comment: A controller action converts to a url based on the controller name and action method name.  Why would there ever be any references directly to a controller action that isn't a reference to a unit test.

Comment: I think it would be pretty non-trivial (if not NP) to implement what you want. You're looking for code that executes an HTTP request directed at that particular controller action, which could be JavaScript or an HTML form or hyperlink. I think ReSharper tries it, though.

Comment: @CodeCaster a POST would still be accessible, whether Javascript in a View called it or not.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I don't know what you mean by that. I mean that the tool would have to scan all code in your solution to determine whether an HTML form or piece of JavaScript code creates a call to that action, and has to accomodate for the applied routing while doing that.

Comment: @nbokmans No, there is no such option in my right click menu, or at least I can't find it. There's only "Find references", which (obviously) won't work. Are you perhaps using any plugins that might make that option appear?

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos The issue is that I cannot easily determine if a method is being used, or when it is being used. I'll elaborate a bit in the question, sorry if I was unclear.

Comment: @Culme that is an *action*, not a method. It means that your application will accept POST requests to it from the browser and route it to that method. You can't know who is going to make that call in advance. Normally, the method will be called by scripts in your View or in response to form submissions. There are no direct references to the actions

Comment: @Culme in WebForms, did you see any references to a WebForm class? This is no different.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos Please don't make this an MVC vs WebForms battle. I am not bashing MVC, I am just looking for a way to manage something that I find difficult.

Comment: @Culme ?? Where did that come from?? I'm saying that just as you'd never expect to see a reference to a webforms page, because it's available to everyone just by existing, you won't find a reference to a controller's action because it's available to anyone just because it's there. Both of them *define* URLs. *Resharper* tries to parse the JS scripts in views to find possible references to actions, but that's not a reference in the way you mean

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos I am sorry, I misinterpreted the intention with that comment. I get your point and it is highly valid. And by all means, figuring out if or from where a Web Forms page is being referenced is just as difficult. Or finding out if a web service is being called in a web forms app, same thing. Though in MVC so much is based on those "loose connections", I often find the need to locate references. Sorry again, I appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the options is Resharper - it more or less can determine where you use `Html.ActionLink()` or `Html.BeginForm()` that points to a controller action. But it won't detect any posts/redirects done from JS.

Also another thing you can do is use [T4MVC](https://github.com/T4MVC/T4MVC/) to make the links from views statically typed, so you can search on references.

Text search through the solution can help, but not always good as you already discovered - how many references to string `Index` do you have in an average MVC project? So this will help with distinctive controller/action names, but not with common names.

Apart from that you are on your own. If you try doing something clever, like in JS concatenate strings to give you the right endpoint - you are in trouble.

Comment: How do you do this with Resharper?

Answer (score 3):

Controller methods are not directly referenced from any part of the code (therefore 0 references), but they are dynamically invoked based on RouteTable which maps controller methods on startup `RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);` in global.asax "implicitly" which would map them as /controller_name/action_name or these can be changed by either editing 
`RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)` or using attributes:

```
[Route("myAction")]
public ActionResult MyAction() {
...
}
```

which would bind it to /myAction (without controller name)

further reading:

[MSDN - Understanding MVC Application Execution Process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381612%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

[Lifecycle of an ASP.NET MVC 5 Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/lifecycle-of-an-aspnet-mvc-5-application)

[ASP.NET MVC Routing Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs)

Answer (score 1):

Another option if you know the application fairly well.  Put a breakpoint on the controller action and then run some tests of the application.